# Identify a component (compoent with hex screw) on a garage door opener

Tags: rf, identification

[image]

I'm trying to disable the receiver circuit on a garage door opener ***due to security concerns with the old rolling code algorithms*** and can't identify this component. I've seen these before but I'm not sure what it is or what its purpose is.

Regarding disabling the receiver circuit. I've already un-soldered the antenna and a resistor to the antenna with no positive results.

Thanks! 
[image: Garage door opener PCB]

Comment: Well it says L1, leading one to suspect that it might be an adjustable inductor (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=adjustable+inductor&tbm=isch)

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a "vacation" or security setting for the opener?  Many have that feature to disable remote operation but still allow the door to be controlled by the manual switch.

Comment: Funny to see a 2 layer board routed as 1 layer, with a big ground pour.

Answer (score 6):

That's a variable inductor, probably part of the RF tuning circuit.

Comment: and messing with or removing it will almost certainly disable the receiver.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was thinking and hoping for! Thanks!

Comment: I think removal of the variable inductor is the next step.

Comment: @brhans "[Move it too much and the receiver may not work at it's usual distance.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/302177/102305)" might be a better way to say it. Disable means absolutely won't work, and has different safety implications than just a dramatic reduction in range. It's a fine point I know.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve 90+% blocking of the original remotes. I have several units to modify and for the first one I have removed the variable inductor. I will update tomorrow on the level of success.

Comment: just a solder blob over the pins on the bottom should be enough, and probably easier than a tidy removal.  not easier than bolt cutters though.

Answer (score 5):

The part is a variable inductor, like a potentiometer but for inductance instead of resistance. The receiver is likely calibrated for best performance by adjusting that inductor. Move it too much and the receiver may not work at it's usual distance. This would be better than taking it out.

Alternatively, just wrap the circuit with metal (don't short it out). Putting it in a solid metal box acts like a Faraday cage and would eliminate or highly reduce/attenuate any signal received. A foil bag works great if you close it right.

**But since you want to disable the RF circuit due to security concerns, then sure, take it off.** Or trace everything to the input pin of the microcontroller and cut the trace.

Comment: Is there a negative impact if I remove the whole variable inductor? My understanding is that removal of the inductor will completely isolate & remove the IC ability to "see" the code being sent by the remotes since the signal will be so weak and full of noise that it won't receive the full code.  Correct?

Comment: Sure, yes, If the inductor is part of the RF circuit. It's also fairly destructive and makes it harder for you to change your mind in the future. I'm still unsure on ***why*** you want to do this though.

Comment: The system is an older rolling code system that was hacked and a vehicle take with at least one of the remotes for the old wireless garage door system.. The upgraded Camberlain security 2.0+ upgrade does not use the original receiver.

I'm completely disabling the original receiver to eliminate the possibility that the old remote or hacking can be used again. The new security 2.0+ system may not be a huge improvement but at least its supposed to be 900Mhz as opposed to 300-400Mhz

Comment: Well, that's important to know. In that case destructive changes aren't a problem